# Dart Decode JSON API response with escaped characters

Tags: flutter, dart

I have below API response from a node.js server and am failing to have it decoded in my dart-flutter using dart convert

```dart
{
    "result": "successful",
    "data": {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "supportedcountries",
        "value": "[{\"code\":\"BA\",\"name\":\"Bosnia & Herzegovina\",\"callingCodes\":[\"+387\"]},{\"code\":\"UG\",\"name\":\"Uganda\",\"callingCodes\":[\"+256\"]},{\"code\":\"CA\",\"name\":\"Canada\",\"callingCodes\":[\"+1\"]},{\"code\":\"AE\",\"name\":\"United Arab Emirates\",\"callingCodes\":[\"+971\"]},{\"code\":\"US\",\"name\":\"United States\",\"callingCodes\":[\"+1\"]},{\"code\":\"KE\",\"name\":\"Kenya\",\"callingCodes\":[\"+254\"]},{\"code\":\"GB\",\"name\":\"United Kingdom\",\"callingCodes\":[\"+44\"]}]",
        "secure": 0,
        "updated_at": "2018-10-13T14:20:05.000Z",
        "updated_by": null
    }
}
```

When I try decoding it using json.decode, I get below error:

```dart
Failed to load "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myapp/paytimeAfrica/paytime_africa/test/main.dart":
  Unexpected character (at character 2)
  {result: successful, data: {id: 12, name: supported_countries, value: [{"co...
   ^

  dart:convert                                                                                       JsonDecoder.convert
  test/main.dart 21:43
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Unexpected character (at character 2) {result: successful,
```

It is complaining about the r in result, maybe it needs to see a " mark. ie "result"

Without seeing the code, not sure how you are feeding it into the decoder, but you can add ' around the whole json string, or convert " to \" so that you don't lose the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

json dynamic for jsonobject

```
  var url = "..../shop/";
  http.get(url).then((res) {
    dynamic list=convert.jsonDecode(res.body);
    setState(() {
      for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
        {
          Datmodel_shop dp=new Datmodel_shop();
          dp.result=list['result'];

        }
    });
  });
```